# C#.net windows service application

Tags: c#, .net

While installing the windows service application i was prompted for set service login with username and password to be entered if i enter my windows login username and 
password or any other password to set the login i get the error 1001 that invalid username and password and sometimes no mapping between account name and password

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to provide the domain name with the user name like `domain\user` or refer to the local machine with `.\user`

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the prompt completely, I do the following:

1. Open the design view of the ProjectInstaller.
2. Select the serviceProcessInstaller and press F4 to open its properties.
3. Change the Account property to LocalSystem.

You can view a description of LocalSystem and the other options for that property on MSDN if you search for "ServiceAccount Enumeration".  The ServiceAccount enum is part of the System.ServiceProcess namespace.